# var and function working in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I was trying to achieve with the code below is that when the generate button is clicked and if the `html` variable is checked then do something - in this case load an alert however from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3raedwf4/) you can see it is working in the complete opposite way.

Why is it doing this? and how do I resolve it to work how I want it too - you can see that I also have to do it for another check box too :)

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="form-group formGroup10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input id="html" type="checkbox" value="">
                <strong>Download as a HTML file</strong></label>
                <br/>
            <label><input id="showInline" type="checkbox" value="">
            <strong>Show as HTML Code</strong></label>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <button type="button" id="generate" class="btn btn-primary formButton10">Generate</button>
        </div>
```

**JS:**

```
var html     = $('#showInline');
    var file     = $('#html');

    $("#generate").click(function(){
        html.change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            alert('hello');
        }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to have a change event. You can remove it to work.

use this way:

```
$("#generate").click(function(){
    //html.change(function(){
    if(html.is(':checked'))
    {
        alert('hello');
    }

    //});
});
```

What you are doing:

You are binding a `change` event in the `click` event. so when you click it first time it registers the change event on the `html`.

---

*I also have to do it for another check box too*

For this you can simplify this as:

```
$("#generate").click(function(){
    if($(this).closest('.form-group').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('id') === "showInline")
    {
        alert('showInline');
    }else{
        alert('html');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) understood 8min until I can accept :) THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You were binding a change event everytime on click of generate. You should change to

```
var html     = $('#showInline');
var file     = $('#html');
html.change(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
   {
    alert('hello');
   }
});

$("#generate").click(function(){
   html.trigger('change')
});
```